# Simple layout via Flex Box

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a common html structure for my website using bootstrap 4, the  common elements are: `sidebar`, `h1` and `content`.

The main task is arranging them properly based on the screen size:

1. In mobile view they should go in the following order: h1, sidebar and content, like this:

[image]

2. In desktop view they should go like this:

[image]

Here is my codepin: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ejLroV

Comment: please edit your codepen as the css is not correctly written and refreshing the screen in a continuous loop

Comment: hi, it's ok for me, try again please

Comment: you can use bootstrap order-classes to achieve that - http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#order-classes

Comment: I already tried but no luck, I would be very appreciate if you can show it on my codepin

Comment: damn I have some sort of bug it's still flickering :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said earlier in above comments, you can achieve that using - bootstrap `order-classes` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#order-classes, pleae have a look at the below working snippet, hope it helps :)

```css
aside {
  background: grey;
  height: 300px;
}

h1 {
  background: green;
}

section {
  background: #c1c1c1;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row d-lg-block">
    <h1 class="col-12 order-1 col-lg-9 float-lg-right order-lg-2">H1 Title</h1>
    <aside class="col-12 order-2 col-lg-3 float-lg-left order-lg-1">Sidebar</aside>
    <section class="col-12 order-3 col-lg-9 float-lg-right order-lg-3">Content</section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Girish,
Your code is working but the main goal was adding the `d-lg-block` class to the container, sure thing the `float-lg-*` classes did the job as well.

So the order works for flex only, in block the float do the job.

Thanks!

Comment: I have edited your code, unnecessary classes removed. You may change the description above the code or I can do it.

Comment: that edit was causing issues in mobile screen did you look at that while doing that edit? you can `copy snippet to answer` and answer your own question no harm in that :D

Comment: You can reject it :)
Also it's ok in mobile, what is wrong for you?